# print def into tkinter window ,when push button?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, printing

how i can use my def "main" or "CheckIP(listIP)" to print it to my tkinter window, when i'm push button...?
Probably need to input my console information like "ping addresses"

**then i have in console:**

**192.168.0.90
inactive
192.168.0.10
inactive
192.168.0.12
inactive
192.168.88.1 inactive** - and i wanna see this information in my tkinter window

pls help :(

Here my code:

```
#Modules
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import simpledialog
import os
import platform
import subprocess


#Parameters for window
root = Tk()
root.title("Пинг МКУ")
root.geometry("300x200")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root['bg'] = '#ccc'


#Main function for ping our devices
def main():
    listIP = list()
    OpenFile(listIP)
    CheckIP(listIP)
#Open txt file with number's
def OpenFile(listIP):
    File = open('ipping.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    for IP in File:
        listIP.append(IP[:-1])
    File.close()

    return listIP

#Chek our adresses
def CheckIP(listIP):
     with open('ipping.txt', 'r') as f:
        for ip in f:
            result = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-c", "1", "-n", "-W", "2", ip], stdout=f, stderr=f).wait()
            if result:
                return ip, "inactive"
            else:
                return ip, "active"

#Event
#secondary_but_ping = Checkbutton ( text = 'Пинговать каждые 5 минут')
Ping = Button( text = 'Пингануть',
               font = 'consolas 13',
               bg = '#48494f',
               fg = '#eff5c9',
               activeforeground = '#eff5c9',
               activebackground = '#6e6f73',
               width = '22',
               height = '2',
               command = main)

textVar = StringVar()
Ping_1 = Label( textvariable = textVar )
Ping_1.pack()

def button1():
    temp = textVar.get()
    textVar.set( temp + "\n" + CheckIP('listIP') ) # "\n" is newline character


Ping.bind('<Button-1>', button1)

root.mainloop()

main()
```

problem solved thanks to K. Stergiou , but now i have problem with tkinter, i need to ping all of my txt addresses, but now ping only 1 addresses

[Tkinter window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fNVu.png)

Comment: The return statement will exit the `CheckIP()` after the first ping completed.  And you don't need to open the text file in `CheckIP()` because you can use the passed `listIP`.

Comment: so how it is works? I need to del my def Checkip? I don't understand you

Comment: When you click the `Ping` button, both `main()` (via `command` option) and `button1()` (via `bind()`) will be executed.  Which function do you want actually?

Comment: I wanna use tkinter, for click on button and then code will be execute to print my code "multi ping adresses"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not call `return` within the for loop inside `CheckIP()` function as it will terminate the function after the first call of `subprocess.Popen(...)`.

You should save the individual ping result into a list and update the label using the result list.

Also you should not use `command` option and `bind()` together because the callbacks assigned to those options will be executed together when the `Ping` button is clicked.

Below is an simplified example based on yours:

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess

#Parameters for window
root = Tk()
root.title("Пинг МКУ")
root.geometry("300x200")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root['bg'] = '#ccc'


#Chek our adresses
def CheckIP():
    results = []
    with open('ipping.txt', 'r') as f:
        for ip in f.read().splitlines():
            rv = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-c", "1", "-n", "-W", "2", ip]).wait()
            results.append(ip+(" inactive" if rv else " active"))
    textVar.set('\n'.join(results))

Button(text='Пингануть',
       font='consolas 13',
       bg='#48494f',
       fg='#eff5c9',
       activeforeground='#eff5c9',
       activebackground='#6e6f73',
       width=22,
       height=2,
       command=CheckIP).pack()

textVar = StringVar()
Label(textvariable=textVar).pack(fill=X)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In `CheckIP()` you are printing the strings to the console but you need to return them so they can be used in Ping_1.
Check this out:

```
def CheckIP(listIP):
     with open('ipping.txt', 'r') as f:
        for ip in f:
            result = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-c", "1", "-n", "-W", "2", ip], stdout=f, stderr=f).wait()
            if result:
                return ip + "inactive" # string concatenation
            else:
                return ip + "inactive"
```

In order to ping multiple addresses create a string variable (tkinter.StringVar()) and use it to change the contents of the `Ping_1` label:

```
textVar = StringVar()
textVar.set("example placeholder")
Ping_1 = Label( textvariable = textVar )

def button1():
    temp = textVar.get()
    textVar.set( temp + "\n" + CheckIP('listIP') ) # "\n" is newline character
    Ping_1.pack()

Ping.bind('<Button-1>', button1)
```

I forgot that you need to `.pack()` Ping_1 each time you change the `textVar` variable

Comment: thank you a lot! But i have another problem right now... Check description pls...

Comment: I'm sorry I thought that would solve the problem. please tell me where to look (by description you mean the initial question?)

Comment: Check the description right now pls :) I added in the description below

Comment: I added some code to solve your problem (let me know if it works)

Comment: now tkinter window is empty... :(
Console empty too

I'm added new code into description

Comment: check new button1()

Comment: nope, again. same problem, but now it's empty at all (don't have white window)

Comment: contact me on twitter if you can https://twitter.com/kostastergiou